# Uncaught Error: Must set options.password in Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, meteor

I am trying to create multiple users so I did a sample example of "Create Users" using `Accounts.createUser`. I have added a packages `accounts-base` and `accounts-password` also. But I got an error `Must set options.password in Meteor`. I have no idea what happening. Check out the code code below.

**Only clicking Register Button at that time I got the error**

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>loginapp</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
    <form id="login-form" action="action">
        <div>
            <h2>Login<h2>
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" /><br>
        <input type="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login" />
        </div>
    </form>

    <form id="register-form" action="action">
        <div>
            <h2> Create Account<h2>
            <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter UserName" /><br>
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder=" Enter Name" /><br>
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder=" Enter Email" /><br>
            <input type="password" id="pwd" placeholder=" Enter Password" /><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Register" id="register" />
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.main.events({
        'submit #login-form': function (e, t) {
            // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
            console.log("You pressed the button LOGIN ");
            e.preventDefault();
            // retrieve the input field values
            var email = t.find('#email').value
                , password = t.find('#pwd').value;
            console.log(email);
            Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    Session.set("loginError", true);
                } else {
                    console.log(" Login Success ");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    Template.main.events
    ({
        'submit #register-form': function (e, t) {

            console.log("You pressed the button Register ");
            e.preventDefault();
            var username = t.find('#username').value
                , name = t.find('#name').value
                , email = t.find('#email').value
                , password = t.find('#pwd').value;


            Accounts.createUser({email: email, password: password, username: username, }, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Register Successfully");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        // code to run on server at startup
        if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {
            Accounts.createUser
            ({
                username: 'username',
                email: 'abc.n@gmail.com',
                password: '123456',
                profile: {
                    first_name: 'fname',
                    last_name: 'lname',
                    company: 'CubeTech',
                }
            }) //Added close parenthesis.
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in these two lines

```
 var email = document.getElementById('email');
 var password = document.getElementById('pwd');
```

`getElementById` returns only a reference to the element, not the value.

Change them to

```
 var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
 var password = document.getElementById('pwd').value;
```

Comment: After changing as you told Its works Successfully,Thank you.@Tobold.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can accept my answer if it solves your problem by clicking on the check mark beside it.

Comment: I have tries to create multiple users in this time i got this error i.e Uncaught Error: Must set options.password So what i can do for this problem and also changed to post of my code please check once also.@Tobold

Answer (score -3):

You must add accounts-base package your project.

Comment: yeah,I added accounts-base package even though suffer from same error.@Uğur Toprakdeviren

Comment: true but `accounts-base` is automatically added when adding `accounts-password`